# .NET System.MissingMethodException Error in Console Application (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple .NET console application that I am using to test some new libraries I wrote and I keep receiving a `System.MissingMethodException` on a certain method in the console Program.cs file itself. The method worked previously, then all of a sudden the app started throwing the `System.MissingMethodException` error when that method is called (before even entering the method.

What I tried:

- Cleaning application
- Rebuilding
- Removing all references to the libraries I am testing
- Deleting all of the dll files from the bin folders for all of the programs

Why is it still throwing an error? I referenced these questions already:

[System.MissingMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592782/system-missingmethodexception)

[System.MissingMethodException: Method not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that the System.MissingMethodException did not happen "all of a sudden" as I mention above. Instead, I had renamed my project and the Default namespace and Assembly name were still set in the Application settings to the previous name (I guess I thought it would have updated these?).

By updating these manually to the new name in the project properties (right-click the project and select properties), that method is now "found" by the application when called: see image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these options:

1) Make sure an old version is not in the GAC

2) Restart Visual Studio

3) Restart your computer